# one class CRF source code for outlier detection - C++

Tags: c++, machine-learning, computer-vision, outliers, causality

Can anyone suggest me a C++ library for one class conditional random field? which can be used for abnormality detection.

Comment: Try this one which may not be exact but close to what you are looking for http://dlib.net/one_class_classifiers_ex.cpp.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two self-written libraries for your referece:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/hcrf/

http://flexcrfs.sourceforge.net/